# Empty generated csv to download

Tags: php, csv

With this code I generate a correct cvs (on server) but when I added the headers to create a download the downladed fle is empty.
Resume: On server is correct but the download is an empty file.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv');
    ......
    .....
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    $header = array('TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME','DATA_TYPE','CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH','CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH','NUMERIC_PRECISION', 'DATETIME_PRECISION'/*, 'TABLE_NUMBER'*/, 'RELATED_TABLE');
    fputcsv($fp, $header,';');
    foreach ($result as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields,';');
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: How do you output file contents for downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
```

Can you try with:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
```

Also I am not sure from where `$result` is coming from.

And why this `/*, 'TABLE_NUMBER'*/` in the `$header` array variable?

> Open the output stream

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

Comment: don't worry about how the file is created correctly only is empty on the download

Comment: have you modified the header?

Comment: Solved  with `$outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');`